# Why does scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage need a metric?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

We're required to pass a distance matrix, so there should be no need to calculate any additional distances, right?  What am I missing?

Documentation here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html

Answer (score 3):

The `linkage` function does not need the `metric` argument, **unlees you pass in your original observations instead of a distance matrix**.

From your posted link

> y : ndarray
>   [...] Alternatively, a collection of m observation vectors in n dimensions may be passed as an m by n array.

The `linkage` function checks, if you passed in a valid distance matrix - presumable using [`is_valid_y`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.is_valid_y.html#scipy.spatial.distance.is_valid_y) / [`is_valid_dm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.is_valid_dm.html#scipy.spatial.distance.is_valid_dm) - and if not it will first apply `pdist` with the metric you have specified (and euclidean metric if nothing has been specified).

Comment: Is this the correct use of custom distance metric? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153829/custom-cluster-colors-of-scipy-dendrogram-in-python-link-color-func

Answer (score 0):

I think the metric is used for calculating the distance between the newly formed cluster ( depending in which method we use)